# Google tag manager - Commerce not working

Tags: google-tag-manager

We have done below things.

https://developers.google.com/tag-manager/enhanced-ecommerce#checkout

https://support.google.com/tagmanager/answer/6107169

1. Added below code on checkout success page.

> ```
> window.dataLayer = window.dataLayer || {};
> window.dataLayer.push({
>   'event': 'purchase',
>   'transactionId': <order id>,
>   'transactionTotal' : <order total>
> });
> ```

2. Ecommerce settings are already enabled.
3. Created transactionId
   & transactionTotal data layer variables in GTM.
4. We have set this
   to fire on Transaction level on GTM.

[image]

What I am still missing?

Comment: Your code if for Ecommerce Standard but your documentation link are for Enhanced Ecommerce. Try to use Enhanced Ecommerce, you don't need to create DL variable just flag 'Enable Enhanced Ecommerce Features' and 'Use data layer' in the tag 
triggered by the event 'purchase'.

Comment: Hi @MichelePisani. So do I need to change in the script? If yes, then what it will be.

Comment: Change the script using parameters in dataLayer.push with Enhanced Ecommerce sintax for purchase. Then create an Analytics event in GTM triggered by purchase event with config describe above in my previous comment.

Comment: I tried but seems not working still.

Comment: It is probably a configuration problem. Try to insert some screenshots of your configuration, on the page and on GTM and on GA. Are the pages tracked? Is the purchase page tracked? Do you detect the event 'purchase' in GTM preview?